# Animation time with gganimate

Tags: r, tidyverse, gganimate

I want to make a plot animate. I need that the points appear and disappear, but only make that the movements of points.

```
set.seed(1)
library(tidyverse)
library(gganimate)
df <- tibble(
  x = rnorm(100)
  , y = rnorm(100)
  , size = rep(c(2, 3, 4, 5), 25)
  , cl = sample(c("a", "b"), 100, T)
  , time = rep(1:10, 10) #|> lubridate::year()
)
p2 <-
  df |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, size = size, color = cl) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 12)) +
  transition_reveal(time) +
  #enter_fade()
  #transition_manual(time) +
  shadow_mark(past = F, future = T)
animate(p2, renderer = gifski_renderer("sa.gif"))
```

Comment: Hi @Miguel Angel Acosta Chinchilla. Your animation works fine on my computer. So, not sure to fully understand your request. Cheers.

Comment: @lovalery, I need that the points appean and desappear but in the same position, not movement like my code.

Comment: O.K. Thank you very much for your feedback. So the answer of @Kat seems to be what you are looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to animate by rows or by variable, just all at once, you can use any of the `enter` states and `transition_layers`. It won't show the final transition, but it will only animate the entrance. I added `enter_fade()` so you would see the entrance.

[image]

```
p2 <-
  df |>
  ggplot() +
  aes(x, y, size = size, color = cl) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 12)) +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_layers(layer_length = 2, 
                    transition_length = 2) +
  enter_fade()
```

---

#### Update:

---

In your comment, you asked if you could first should the group `a`, then group `b`. I assume this is what you're looking for.

[image]

```
p3 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(data = filter(df, cl == "a"),
             aes(x, y, color = cl, size = size)) + 
  geom_point(data = filter(df, cl == "b"),
             aes(x, y, color = cl, size = size)) +
  scale_size(range = c(5, 12)) +
  theme_bw() +
  transition_layers(layer_length = 2, 
                    transition_length = 2) +
  enter_fade()

p3
```

Comment: This excellent for my request. I try to find this animation, **thanks**.

Comment: @ Kat, Exist form that appear each circle type. For example first point `a` and next `b`. In different time lapse. But in final all points. For better explanation of data.

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't understand what you're trying to say in your comment. Can you try to explain it another way or provide an example of what you would like? (Even if you copy it from somewhere. That 'somewhere' doesn't have to have an origin in R, either.)

Comment: Ok excuse me, I would like the graph to show first the circles of **cl** `a` and after a while the **cl** `b`, since each one has a different color it can be better appreciated. And that in the end if both `a` and `b` are seen.
Because this show all circles in the same time. Tnks!

Comment: I updated my answer. Let me know if there is anything else.

Comment: Its perfect @Kat, thanks you.